Using dependencies when developing an android library
I am developing an Android library, i use some dependencies in the project module which is published to a local maven repo, this is how i declare my dependencies in my gradle.build.kts:
    dependencies {

    // Retrofit
    implementation(libs.retrofit)
    implementation(libs.retrofit.gson)
    implementation(libs.okhttp)
    implementation(libs.okhttp.logging)

    // room
    implementation(libs.room.runtime)
    implementation(libs.room.ktx)
    ksp(libs.room.compiler)
    testImplementation(libs.room.testing)

    // Work Manager
    implementation(libs.work.runtime.ktx)

    // Play services
    implementation(libs.play.services.location)

    // DI
    implementation(libs.koin.android)
}


my publishing section i straight forward:
publishing {
    publications {
        create<MavenPublication>("release") {
            artifact("$buildDir/outputs/aar/${project.name}-release.aar")
            groupId = "com.mylibrary.android"
            artifactId = "core"
            version = project.extra["baseVersionName"] as String
        }
    }
    repositories {
        maven {
            url = uri("${project.buildDir}/repo")
        }
    }
}


I run ./gradlew assembleRelease, than ./gradlew publish and get an AAR file in a local location.
However, when i try to use this SDK in a sample app, using the line
implementation("com.mylibrary.android:core:0.3.1")

I get errors for java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: on my dependencies, as my sample app dont, nor do i want it to, declare any dependencies in its gradle file.
I have seen solutions for using api instead of implementation however this did not change the error.
I have seen talk of fat-aar but i am not sure that is the correct approach, does anyone know what is the right approach to have dependencies in a library that can be published with it? should they be published with it at all?

"should they be published with it at all?" -- IMHO, no. Are you publishing to Maven local or some other Maven repository? If so, then api for transitive dependencies should be working. I am unclear if  "get an AAR file in a local location" means Maven local or not.

It means i am building a AAR in a folder build/repo in my own local project, than accessing it locally by another project by specifying the path to that folder.
In what conditions is api not suppose to be working? i will be happy to post more information if needed

"than accessing it locally by another project by specifying the path to that folder" -- don't do that. Use Maven local or another Maven repository. Dependency information is a Maven repository thing, not an AAR thing. Also note that what you wrote in that comment seems to run counter to the implementation("com.mylibrary.android:core:0.3.1") from your question, which is not "specifying the path to that folder".

I may be missing something basic here, in my sample app project level gradle I added maven { path to folder where arr is } and in the app level gradle I used the implementation() is my problem in the way I am consuming the Library or in the way I am publishing it?

"in my sample app project level gradle I added maven { path to folder where arr is }" -- I recommend that you do not do that. Use Maven local or some other Maven repository. Again: dependencies are a Maven thing, not an AAR thing.

Thanks to @CommonsWare i have managed to understand a crusial step in library publication which is the difference between packaging an AAR file and creating a Maven repo.
By adding a pom block to my publishing script in the gradle,build.kts i added the neccessary metadata for the maven repo to be able to handle my libraries depencdencies without having tham packaged in my AAR file
publishing {
    publications {
        create<MavenPublication>("release") {
            artifact("$buildDir/outputs/aar/${project.name}-release.aar")
            groupId = "com.library.android"
            artifactId = "core"
            version = project.extra["baseVersionName"] as String

            pom {
                name.set("SDK name")
                description.set("Description of library")
                url.set("http://www.url.co")

                withXml {
                    val dependenciesNode = asNode().appendNode("dependencies")
                    configurations["api"].allDependencies.forEach {
                        val dependencyNode = dependenciesNode.appendNode("dependency")
                        dependencyNode.appendNode("groupId", it.group)
                        dependencyNode.appendNode("artifactId", it.name)
                        dependencyNode.appendNode("version", it.version)
                        dependencyNode.appendNode("scope", "compile") // "compile" for API, "runtime" for implementation
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
    }
}

